# How to execute formula in cell (row,col) from vba routine

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, worksheet

being a freshman with regard to Excel, here is what I would like to achieve:

In cell(row,col) there is a worksheet function, in this case `RANDARRY(rows;cols;min;max;TRUE)`.
I now would like to write a vba routine that simply executes whatever is written in `cell(row,col)`.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "executes whatever is written in cell(row,col)".

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheet("Sheet1").Calculate` should recalculate all the formulas on the sheet.

`Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Calculate` should recalculate the formulas in range A1 to A10 in Sheet1.

Alternatively pushing <kbd>F9</kbd> does trigger calculation without using VBA.

Comment: Formeln > Berechnungsoptionen -> Manuell : dann wird bei F9 ALLES neu berechnet. Das will ich eben vermeiden. Ansonsten: vielen herzlichen Dank!

Comment: @WernerAlber Please note that Stack Overflow is english only. Actually `Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Calculate` will only calculate that specific range. So this should solve your issue.